# Fastest way to union two strings

Tags: string, performance

I'm looking for a fast way to make a union (in terms of set theory) of two strings' characters. For example 'copy' union 'creepy' should give 'copyre'. I need to get all the letters used in a file consisting of *a lot* of short strings (50 chars tops I think).

At the moment I:

- take a string read from the file
- iterate over its letters and search for each of them in the set of used letters (stored as a sorted string) using binary search.

This needs to handle unicode characters, so making a table with booleans and marking each of the letters that appeared won't work. Any ideas how to make this faster?

Comment: 'copyrep' has the p in it twice, is that intended? If so, what are the rules of this union?

Comment: Not intended, my mistake

Comment: What do you want to do about oddities such as combining diacritic marks, left-to-right marker, zero-width space, that whole can of worms?

Comment: Do you process each individual string more than once? If so then I'd suggest pre-sorting/canonizing them so you can do a simple parallel iteration to form the individual unions later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get all the letters, I recommend to use a bitvector with one entry for each letter and mark the appearance. A bitvector is an array of integers which is interpreted as an n-ary boolean array where the n-th bit indicates the n-th boolean. Access time is constant. If the size of the set of characters is either too large or not known a-priori, you need a different set implementation. However, in any case you should use an existing data structure (e.g. [this one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/charset)) for a set instead of inventing your own.

The algorithm would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
   bits[mem[i]] = true;
```

This is linear time. It does not get any better, I think. You might be able to get some constant factor by using clever CPU aligning and parallelization - that depends on the problem size, though.

Comment: It needs to work with unicode characters, so listing all possibilities is out of my range. If I added a new entry each time a letter appears how is that different from my current solution? I still need to search for the letter in the vector. Or just I can't see how is that faster?

Comment: @ElevenFortyOne you could use a hashset though

Comment: @ElevenFortyOne: Are you targetting an embedded device? A full Unicode bitmap would "only" need 136k of RAM, and unless your dataset is particularly crazy you're unlikely to see anything but a small cache-friendly subset. Just make two passes over the strings to manually clear only the flags raised at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first string, and **put each char** in it some hashed set, like [`java.util.HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Take the second string and **put each chars** in the same hashed set.

**Iterate over the set** to the get the "union string" out. This string will probably be in random order.

Another promising solution is to use a data structure that specializes in integer sets - since chars are represented as integers internally in some way.

One example of such an integer set is Zach Tellman's [`data.int-map`](https://github.com/clojure/data.int-map) for Clojure. It is described as "A straightforward port of Okasaki and Gill's "Fast Mergeable Integer Maps", which can be found at http://ittc.ku.edu/~andygill/papers/IntMap98.pdf." The work by Okasaki and Gill seems to be implemented in Haskell.

There are probably similar efficient integer set implementations in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

When you're talking about input sizes with an upper bound of something like 50 unicode characters (and I'm assuming your average case is far smaller), then a lot of algorithmic options are out. We're typically looking at bare metal micro-optimizations. With those kinds of miniscule input sizes, bubble sort can actually outperform quicksort.

If we're trying to compute a union between two strings of 8 characters, for example, the cost of constructing an auxiliary structure or performing a sort on the fly is likely going to require more time than it saves vs. a simple brute force solution that even has quadratic complexity. I think this might be true even if you can manage to reuse the same data structure just for memory/cache-related reasons.

If you can pre-sort both strings in advance (ex: already storing sorted strings in your file), then you can probably get an improvement since then a union between two sorted strings can be found in a single linear pass (just use two pointers/indices). That's assuming you can sort all of this in advance outside this time-critical loop.

Otherwise you're probably looking at micro-optimizations and want to grab the profiler here. The highest priority among these might be memory-related given the relative effort/reward ratio. For example, you don't want to be constantly allocating and freeing string objects (and potentially incurring more cache misses depending on what you do afterwards) to do this and want to reuse the same buffers, unless your strings are just allocated on the hardware stack (in which case allocation/deallocation is generally dirt cheap).

Next might be multithreading, but for this route, you probably want more work for each thread to do than computing a union between two teeny strings. The scheduling overhead is likely going to outweigh the benefits here, so you want each thread/parallel iteration to compute unions of multiple (possibly quite many like hundreds) of strings.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to get the union is to concatenate the two strings, sort this array, and create a new array without any duplicates.

An (untested) example in Java would be

```
String copy = "copy";
String creepy = "creepy";
char[] chars = (copy + creepy).toCharArray();

java.util.Arrays.sort(chars); //puts duplicates side by side

int currentChar = -1; //no risk of initial collision since chars >= 0
int setSize = 0;      //set size, pointer when "compacting" the set

//ignore duplicates, reuses the char[] - garbage in the end!

for (int pos = 0; pos < chars.length; pos++) {
    if (currentChar != (int)chars[pos]) {
        chars[setSize] = chars[pos];
        setSize++;
        currentChar = chars[pos];
    }
}

// please note that Strings are both immutable
// and can be held in memory for long times, don't allocate them for
// intermediate results if you can avoid it.

String result = new String(java.util.Arrays.copyOf(chars, setSize));
```